# How can I fix Datetimepicker bugs to be big size in Monday column?

Tags: html

This is my script

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Dari Tanggal" name="tanggal_awal" id="tanggal_awal" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
```

and this is JS

```
$('#tanggal_awal,#tanggal_akhir').datetimepicker({
    pickTime: false,
    todayBtn    : 'linked',
    minView: 2,
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    autoclose: true,
    orientation : "bottom auto"});
```

[image]

Comment: You should look at what styles or classes are being applied to that column in your browser's dev tools.

Comment: I Use Default Datetime picker assets

Answer (score 0):

Try setting default width of the day with css

```
.datepicker table tr td.day,.datepicker table tr th.day{
    width:30px;
}
```

Comment: Not Work Bro :(

Comment: I can't match your case because I can't see it. Try to select the day with css and set default width

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/R7KJHrg/Screenshot-3.png this is screenshot this bugs